# How to call exe in powershell script with redirection output to log file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

What I want to do is from powershell script run my small program(exe) and put output from this exe to the same log file as other things in powershell script.

Comment: `your.ps1 > your.log`?

Comment: This has been asked many times before, take a look at the answers and have a go: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpowershell%5D+exe+output